# Rails Form_for not submitting parameters only in Chrome Browser

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, google-chrome

I have put together a very simple form that creates a user in the database. It's weird, I have been able to submit the form in both Firefox and Safari; however, when I try to submit it in Chrome it doesn't do anything. The loading wheel spins in the tab as if it's trying to load something but it doesn't even hit the database to return some type of an error. Also, the Save button is greyed out after it is clicked.

It's odd because Chrome is my usual browser for testing and I never had this issue before.

Since it is working in other browsers, I'm left to assume the issue is with Chrome itself. I tried clearing cache and cookies but still having the issue. Since I'm not getting any real feedback from Chrome or Rails I'm kind of stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### new.html.erb

```
<h1>Users#new</h1>
<div>
<%= form_for User.new do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.text_field :email, autocomplete:'username email' %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete:'new-password' %>

  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete:'new-password' %>
  <br>
  <br>
  <%= f.submit 'Save' %>
<% end %>
<div>
```

### user_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.create!(user_params)

    if @user.save
      redirect_to movies_path
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :name, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

### application_html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Testomni</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
    <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried restarting your computer? I find sometimes Chrome's aggressive caching can only be fixed by restarting.

Comment: Oddly enough that's the one thing I haven't tried. Mostly because I'm doing a Time Machine backup on my mac which is an all-day thing, unfortunately. When it's done I'll do that and see if it works.

Comment: Is there any feedback in your `rails s` logs? You could also check the network tab in the browser just to be sure, that it is nothing from the app but the browser.

Comment: No, that's what's weird. There is no feedback from Rails, but when I us it in another browser like Firefox or Safari it works as intended.